# fcntl does not detect Bad file descriptor on socket fd

Tags: c, sockets, fcntl

`fcntl(sockfd,F_GETFD,0)` doesn't detect a bad file descriptor whereas `select` on the same sock fd gives bad file descriptor 
error.

Comment: Could you give some more info? Under what conditions does it happen? What is the value of sockfd? How and when do you do perform this check?

Comment: I have a server and a client .At the server side the socket is not closed but during select it gives bad file descriptor error.The check to find which of the fd had gone bad using fcntl doesnt give any error.

Comment: More likely there is something wrong with your select code. How about you post it?

Comment: What is errno set to when using select()? Is it `(errno == EBADF)`?

Comment: Are you using select() with threads? Where are you creating the socket? Little bit of code will help.